# Regular Expression in java aboute a number(like phone number starting 021 and then two repeated number)?

Tags: java, regex

Regular Expression in java about a number(like phone number starting 021 and then two repeated number) for totally eleven digits, for example:

> ```
>  02177890488
>  or
>  02177098765 
>  or 
>  02199123450
> ```

pls help me,

i tried this:

```
^[0][2][1][1-9]\\1[0-9]{6}$
```

but does not work:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe,

```
^021([0-9])\\1[0-9]{6}$
```

or

```
^021(\\d)\\1\\d{6}$
```

would be OK to start with, and Java uses double-escaping.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VzqT1R/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "^021(\\d)\\1\\d{6}$";
        final String string = "02177890488\n"
             + "02177098765\n"
             + "02199123450\n"
             + "02100890488\n"
             + "02111098765\n"
             + "02122123450\n"
             + "02133123450\n"
             + "02144123450\n"
             + "02155123450\n"
             + "02166123450\n"
             + "02188123450";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You were quite close, you just need to capture the digit you want to backtrack and match again, this pattern will work:

`^021([1-9])\\1\\d{6}$`

Notice that `[0][2][1]` is exactly the same as `021`, and also that the character range `[0-9]` can be simplified to just `\\d`.

Comment: @mmshh You still need the parantheses, like: `([1-9])`.

Comment: i tried this(^021([1-9])\1\d{6}$) but in eclipse show some error about this, and the error is: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Double every backslash then. So `\\1` and `\\d`.

Comment: yeah Thanks a lot